# How To Restore Previous 3 sessions of Safari?

Tags: macos, safari

Everywhere seems to tell you how to open the previous safari session but what about those before that?

I sent my macbook for repair & i only can open my last prev session which probably was opened up by the repair guy but he did not restore the sessions prior to the repair... Any idea how to restore the sessions before that?

Comment: Go to your backup - I would assume that a repairer might have reinstalled the whole OS - You usually have to sign a form that allows them to do that

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, Safari will only save the last session - and no previous sessions before it.

While it won't help you with your current predicament (as @Mark cites, a backup is your best bet), check out the [Safari Restore extension](http://sweetpproductions.com/extensions/extensions.htm) which will enable you to *manually* save & restore different sessions (N.B.: it does **NOT** save different sessions automatically!).